# Loop Through HTML Files in a Folder & Silently Print Them To The Default Printer via IE

Tags: c#

I'm trying to cobble together a short bit of console code to print some HTML files in a folder through Internet Explorer to the default printer. I have found a the following code below from http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2004/06/23/162913.aspx which appears to almost suit my needs.

I have have made a couple of alterations but my programming skills are very limited. I'm looking for some help making sure the syntax is correct and someone to show me how to silently print via Internet Explorer and not to open Internet Explorer as I beleive it stands now.

Any help would be greatly appreaciated...

```
using System
using System.IO

// How much deep to scan. (of course you can also pass it to the method)
const int HowDeepToScan=4; 

public static void ProcessDir(string sourceDir, int recursionLvl) 
{
if (recursionLvl<=HowDeepToScan)
{
// Process the list of files found in the directory. 
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\fileDump\", "*.html");  
foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
{
   // do something with fileName
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName);
}

// Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
string [] subdirEntries = Directory.GetDirectories((@"C:\fileDump);
foreach(string subdir in subdirEntries)
   // Do not iterate through reparse points
   if ((File.GetAttributes(subdir) &
        FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) !=
            FileAttributes.ReparsePoint)

        ProcessDir(subdir,recursionLvl+1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar (but different) problem to solve and the code I used may be able to help you.

**Background to my problem**

Create a program which when used to open a file (in this case .MHTML files) would in fact open it with IE, immediatly print the page and the close IE

**CODE**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        const int PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION = 2;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (Application.Current.Properties["ArgFileName"] != null)
            {
                string fname = Application.Current.Properties["ArgFileName"].ToString();
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fname))
                {
                    fileLabel.Content = "No File Specified";
                }
                else
                {
                    fileLabel.Content = fname;
                    SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
                    IE.DocumentComplete +=new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(IE_DocumentComplete);
                    IE.PrintTemplateTeardown += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_PrintTemplateTeardownEventHandler(IE_PrintTemplateTeardown);
                    IE.Visible = true;
                    IE.Navigate2(fname);    
                }      
            }
        }

       void IE_PrintTemplateTeardown(object pDisp)
        {
            if (pDisp is SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)
            {
                SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)pDisp;               
                IE.Quit();
                System.Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }

       void IE_DocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
        {
            if (pDisp is SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)
            {
                SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)pDisp;               
                IE.ExecWB(SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PRINT, SHDocVw.OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, 2);

            }
        }
    }
```

**NOTES**

Once youve incorporated this into your file loop you would need to change `IE.Visible = true;` to `IE.Visible = false;` this prevents the IE window displaying.

Comment: This is great, thank you Simon. I didn't realise you could open IE up and then print, this is probably more fitting to my requirements. I'm looking forward to giving it a whirl.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't want to sound like an irritating noob but I'm at a loss how how to incorporate the two pieces of code into some thing functional. Your printing method sounds like it would be perfect for what I need but I'm not sure what I'm doing.Would I beable merg the pieces together without creating a partial class?

Comment: the partial class you see in the code is just the class for the programs main window/form. I dont know if your using a command line program WinForms or WPF but you should just be able to drop it in the relevant places.

Comment: Thank you very much Simon, with your code I have been given the guidence needed to add a printing function to my application.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is for the program to be simple command line program.

I've found a slightly simpler way of cycling through my files and I think your code has been added correctly. However I think from the two errors I'm getting it looks like I've over looked something, do you have any suggestions?

Ideally I'm would like the program to stay as a single Class.

My errros are:

> 'Bulk_Pdf.Main.Main(string)': a static constructor must be
>   parameterless (CS0132) - C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\bulkPrint_pdf.cs:16,18
>
> 'Bulk_Pdf.Main.Main(string)': access modifiers are not allowed on
>   static constructors (CS0515) -
>   C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\bulkPrint_pdf.cs:16,18

Do you havee any suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace HTML_Print
{
class Main
{
    private static Main(string dirPath)
    {

        // Define Working Directory
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\fileDump");

        // Define File Type
        foreach (FileInfo finfo in dir.GetFiles("*.html"))

        // Open IE Explorer and Print
        if (Application.Current.Properties["finfo"] != null)
        {
            string fname = Application.Current.Properties["finfo"].ToString();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fname))
            {
                fileLabel.Content = "No File Specified";
            }
            else
            {
                fileLabel.Content = fname;
                SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
                IE.DocumentComplete +=new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(IE_DocumentComplete);
                IE.PrintTemplateTeardown += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_PrintTemplateTeardownEventHandler(IE_PrintTemplateTeardown);
                IE.Visible = true;
                IE.Navigate2(fname);    
            }      
        }
    }

   void IE_PrintTemplateTeardown(object pDisp)
    {
        if (pDisp is SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)
        {
            SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)pDisp;               
            IE.Quit();
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }

   void IE_DocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        if (pDisp is SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)
        {
            SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)pDisp;               
            IE.ExecWB(SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PRINT, SHDocVw.OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, 2);

        }
    }
}


}
```